# How to send push notifications from wordpress to android app?

Tags: android, wordpress, push-notification, onesignal

I am using OneSignal to receive a notification, But I can't find out from the WordPress site to the android app. The app can receive notification from the dashboard to the android app it works great but I want a WordPress site to mobile app for every post.

Answer (score 0):

OneSignal has a pretty good api and php SDK (https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification) so you could just send the notification within the wp_insert_post hook. Make sure you only fire it when the post is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following WordPress plugin to send push notification to the android app when a new post is published on your WordPress site

https://github.com/dream-space/wp-fcm/

This plugin also helps you to send a custom notification to your android app users

Comment: a plugin is not free I want a free plugin.

Comment: This is a free plugin. Just download it and upload it on your WordPress